# Mac OS updating from Mojave to any new OS (Big sur, Monterey

Tags: mac

Has anyone updated active directory bound Macs past Mojave?

I have tried updating to Catalina and newer but every time after logging in to a domain account it just sits there spinning.

The setup is:

- Active Directory bound,
- Jamf enrolled,
- Mobile accounts turned off,
- Local library folder turned off,
- UNC Path enabled - So the library should generate on the network folder

Checking `/library/logs/DiagnosticsReports/` from a Windows 10 station I can see reoccurring CRASH files relating to accountsd happening between 6-7 times a minute (please see a copy of one of them below). As of typing this up, the client computer is still at the pinwheel stage after 22 minutes and the logs are still reporting the same thing.

> Process: accountsd [1987] Path: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Versions/A/Support/accountsd Identifier: accountsd Version: 113 (113) Code Type: X86-64 (Native) Parent Process: ??? [1] Responsible: accountsd [1987] User ID: 795780844

Has anyone came accross a similar issue and resolved it?

Comment: have you tried logging in as a local admin and rebinding to your domain?

Comment: Hi, Yes I have tried a fresh install of Mac OS and manually binding the domain but still occurs.

Comment: And is the network connection still active on the mac when attempting to log in as the domain user? I only ask because we recently had to enable mobile AD accounts on the macs for cached domain user logins to work when network is down on them.

Comment: Hi, Yeah the network connection is active and the domain account does log in. But its just the next part when it start spinning and trying to read / write the library. I believe it something to do with SIP as if I disable it then the library folder generates correctly but it doesn't load properly and generates a new type of error log.

Comment: I do not want to turn on mobile accounts really as I believe it creates a local library on the mac and then it will fill up the users folder on the mac. However turning this on does let the account login correctly but it just adds a shortcut to the UNC path on the dock.